# What are the best metrics for text generation using RNN?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, natural-language

I am experimenting with RNNs to generate automated movie reviews, using [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) as a reference. I am using LSTMs to achieve this. The reviews are generated by randomly sampling from the LSTM language model.

How can I measure the quality of reviews generated? I have explored metrics like BLEU, METEOR and ROGUE. These metrics are well suited for usecases where we know what kind of text to expect. What metrics can I use for my usecase?

Comment: If every letter is randomly how could you predict with any degree of accuracy?

Comment: Once the entire review is generated, may be a metric to test the grammar/reading comprehension. Did not find any online. Passing it to the experts..

Comment: There is nothing unclear with this question. The OP is just asking what are the metrics used for text generation.

Comment: To follow up, the type of text generation you are trying to do is an active area of research and no one has a good metric short of doing human evaluation. You might have better success using perplexity rather than BLUE score.

Comment: Even I was of the opinion that nothing can beat human evaluation for such usecases as of now. I am using perplexity instead of BLEU and getting better results. Thanks for the suggestion @Aaron. Can you post your comment as the answer?

Comment: @bot4u I want to post an answer but it won't let me because they put this question on hold.